# displaying numbers in correct format in textbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, format

the number entered in the textbox is stored as integer,suppose if you enter a number like 0095 on exiting textbox it should displayed "95",also another textbox takes float,if i enter 1.567 it should be displayed as"1.5"...how to do that in C#?

Answer (score 2):

Like most other languages I assume.  In C# when I do something like that, I get the data from the textbox,usually richtextbox, store it as a string.  from there you can typecast it to an int (should you believe that what is being typed is an int) and then do a fairly straight forward trim of the float number.

Use readline to take lines as strings, or just take the whole thing as a string, depending on how you implement it.

Convert strings to ints using:

```
int numVal = Int32.Parse("105");
```

or

```
string text = "500";
int num = int.Parse(text);
```

and then

```
Math.Round(float,decimals)
```

for trimming the float.

Comment: actully textbox takes only ints and float...am validating textbox

Comment: Then yeah, you set the textbox to a string, and parse it for the float or int.